# Server socket accessing from openedge app

Tags: sockets, server, openedge

I did a server-client socket in C#. This is running on network and communicate together.

Now I have to communicate from a openedge progress app client. For connecting to my c# server, I've tried this code:

```
CREATE SOCKET mysocket.

ret = mysocket:CONNECT("-H 192.168.0.8 -S 5463"). /* Point 1 */

IF NOT ret THEN DO: /* Point 2 */

 MESSAGE "Unable to connect to server" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

END.
```

But my client will not connect and I receive the message "Unable to connect."

Is this possible to do or not?

Comment: Have you tried researching that error? 
There's probably a firewall blocking the traffic.

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged C# - it's like tagging anything that connects to a server written in C with the C tag... your question has nothing to do with the C# backend as far as I can see.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, i did a research. I disable windows firewall, all my antivirus software but the client wont connect to the server.

Comment: Well can you ping it? Can you telnet to that port? This isn't anything we can answer; you need to do troubleshooting.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can ping and i can telnet the ip and port. This line seem not connecting : ret = mysocket:CONNECT("-H 192.168.0.8 -S 5463").

Comment: _"I can ping and i can telnet the ip and port"_ - from the OpenEdge server, or wherever this code is running?

Comment: I can ping from command line and i can telnet the ip and port on putty. But from OpenEdge i cant connect.

Comment: "Unable to connect to server" is what you message when the connection fails. But there should also be an error from Progress. For example "Connection failed for host X port Y transport TCP (9407)". Post that error (specifically the number - it's the unique error identifier).

Comment: Also version of OpenEdge would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.

First i use AppBuilder. I open a read_socket.w, which run a file open_socket.p. This wont connect to my server.

I use OpenEdge Developper Studio, create a new form : mySocket.cls. I put a button  with this method :

```
method private void button1_Click( input sender as System.Object, input e as System.EventArgs ):
    define variable mytext as character no-undo.

    define variable i as integer no-undo.

    define variable len as integer no-undo.

    define variable mysocket as handle no-undo.

    define variable mymemptr as memptr no-undo.

    define variable ret as logical no-undo.

    create socket mysocket.

    ret = mysocket:connect("-H 192.168.0.8 -S 5463"). /* Point 1 */

    if not ret then do: /* Point 2 */

     message "Unable to connect to server" view-as alert-box.

    end.



    return.

end method.
```

And this way, the connection happens
Best regards

Comment: Good you solved the issue but this actually doesn't seem to be any different so the error must be in your environment somehow.